# Neo4j Cypher: Create a relationship only if the end node exists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Building on this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13244894/6893866), I want the most performant way to handle this scenario.

```
MERGE (n1{id:<uuid>})
SET n1.topicID = <unique_name1>
IF (EXISTS((a:Topic{id:<unique_name1>})) |  CREATE UNIQUE (n1)-[:HAS]->(a))

MERGE (n2{id:<uuid>})
SET n2.topicID = <unique_name2>
IF (EXISTS((a:Topic{id:<unique_name2>})) |  CREATE UNIQUE (n2)-[:HAS]->(a))
```

Unfortunately, IF doesn't exist, and EXISTS can't be used to match or find a unique node.

- I can't use OPTIONAL MATCH, because then CREATE UNIQUE will throw a null exception (as much as I wish it would ignore null parameters)
- I can't use MATCH, because if the topic doesn't exist, I will will loose all my rows.
- I can't use MERGE, because I don't want to create the node if it doesn't exist yet.
- I can't use APOC, because I have no guarantee that it will be available for use on our Neo4j server.

The best solution I have right now is

```
MERGE (a:TEST{id:1})
WITH a
OPTIONAL MATCH (b:TEST{id:2})
// collect b so that there are no nulls, and rows aren't lost when no match
WITH a, collect(b) AS c
FOREACH(n IN c | CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[:HAS]->(n))
RETURN a
```

However, this seems kinda complicated and needs 2 `WITH`s for what is essentially `CREATE UNIQUE RELATION if start and end node exist` (and in the plan there is an eager). Is it possible to do any better? (Using Cypher 3.1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simplify a quite a bit:

```
MERGE (a:TEST{id:1})
WITH a
MATCH (b:TEST{id:2})
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[:HAS]->(b)
RETURN a;
```

The (single) `WITH` clause serves to split the query into 2 "sub-queries".

So, if the `MATCH` sub-query fails, it only aborts its own sub-query (and any subsequent ones) but does not roll back the previous successful `MERGE` sub-query.

**Note, however, that whenever a final sub-query fails, the `RETURN` clause would return nothing. You will have to determine if this is acceptable.**

Because the above `RETURN` clause would only return something if `b` exists, it might make more sense for it to return `b`, or the path. Here is an example of the latter (`p` will be assigned a value even if the path already existed):

```
MERGE (a:TEST{id:1})
WITH a
MATCH (b:TEST{id:2})
CREATE UNIQUE p=(a)-[:HAS]->(b)
RETURN p;
```

[UPDATE]

In neo4j 4.0+, `CREATE UNIQUE` is no longer supported, so `MERGE` needs to be used instead.

Also, if you want to return `a` even if `b` does not exist, you can use the APOC function [apoc.do.when](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/cypher-execution/conditionals/#conditionals-when):

```
MERGE (a:TEST{id:1})
WITH a
OPTIONAL MATCH (b:TEST{id:2})
CALL apoc.do.when(
  b IS NOT NULL,
  'MERGE (a)-[:HAS]->(b)',
  '',
  {a: a, b: b}) YIELD value
RETURN a;
```

Comment: Is there a way to return node-a even when sub-query fails?

Comment: Thanks. But I tried https://community.neo4j.com/t/how-to-use-if-else-condition-in-neo4j/8665/4?u=devendra0110. It allows returning node-a even if the subquery fails as it only runs when condition is true. But really thanks for answering.

Comment: Yes, that was the old workaround. The APOC procedure was added to avoid having to use it.